# Alexa can't launch skill in beta test

Tags: publish, alexa-skills-kit

I wrote an alexa-Skill whitch is running on my own server.

[everthing looks good at developer.amazon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMD1a.png) configuration seems ok.

Also I can use at the menu point "test" the Service Simulator everything is fine. I get responses from my server can invoke Intents everything looks like it is working.

Now I gave me test free for beta testing. Used the invite link to added the skill to my list and set him active.

Here comes the strange part, if try to launch my skill with alexa, with the invoke name, Alexa response with "entschuldigung ich habe gerade schwierigkeiten versuche es später nochmal" (translated to english "sorry, I got some trouble (issues) try again later")

This is a German skill, so I set german in "Skill information" and set it available in germany under "Countries & Region"

I have no clue why I can't start my skill from my Alexa… maybe some of you had the same Problem and can help me with this issue.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it……

My Invocation Name were "Alexa start |skillname|" as it is shown in the example. So I tried to add another language like the first post suggest, I typed it in the field and got an error msg Invocation Name isn't allowed to contain "alexa".

I had to type "|skillname|" thats all… everything works now…

Answer (score 1):

the amazon echo is configured for Germany too? IMO, did you implement the skill for US version too? change the echo to US lang, and test it there... when I developed the skill, I needed to use US version to beta test... not sure if that was fixed, or how you can test in other versions (I'm in UK)